# Restore data to postgresql database using commandprompt

Tags: postgresql, command-line, database-backups, database-restore

I have a .backup file in D:\test; I need to restore this backup using commandline. I used below command. but it is not working;

```
psql.exe -U username -d dbname -f "d:\backup\myfile.backup"
```

also I used below too

```
psql -h hostname -U username -d databasename -f "D:\backup\myfil.backup"
```

Comment: what error message did you get?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are using Postgresql under Windows.
Then you have to switch to the directory where your *pg_restore.exe* lies.

e.g. create a batch file:

```
set DBname=myDatabaseName
set filename=myfile.backup

cd PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\

pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "%DBname%" --verbose "F:\Backup_DB\%filename%"
```